# How to use inherited objects in parent class functions?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have two classes: **MovableObject** and **GravitySource** that inherited from **MovableObject** (because GravitySources can move too). At **MovableObject** I have function **integrate** that calculates movement params using list of GravitySources.
So, I can't put list of GravitySources into this function. And I don't want to create duplicates of **MovableObject** functions (including **integrate**) in **GravitySource**. So, how to solve this problem? It is C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MovableObject::integrate` function declaration can take a `MovableObject*` pointer as a parameter, something like:

```
return_type MovableObject::integrate(Movable* );
```

In this way, you can pass `GravitySources` to the `Movable::integrate`, and the behaviour will be polymorphic, i.e. you have access to `virtual` functions via the pointer to base `MovableObject*`. Therefore make sure you have some common `virtual` functions that can be called via the pointer to base, and delegate the work to them.

If you want to pass an array of `GravitySources`, then it's a bit more tricky, since you cannot safely use a `MovableObject*` pointer to move through a `GravitySources` array. What you can do though is to forward-declare the class `GravitySources`, then you can declare

```
return_type MovableObject::integrate(GravitySources* );
```

You can use incomplete types via pointers, so the above declaration is OK. Just make sure the implementation of the function comes after the full definition of `GravitySources`. You can now pass arrays of `GravitySources` to your function!

Some toy example below:

```
#include <iostream>

class GravitySources; // need this forward declaration

class MovableObject
{
public:
    void integrate(GravitySources* gs, std::size_t N); // process N GravitySources
    virtual void f(); // our common virtual interface
    virtual ~MovableObject() = default;
};

class GravitySources: public MovableObject
{
    int _label; // label the instance
public:
    GravitySources(int label): _label(label) {}
    void f() override;
};

void MovableObject::integrate(GravitySources* gs, std::size_t N)
{
    // process the GravitySources
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        gs[i].f();
    }
}
void MovableObject::f()
{
    std::cout << "MovableObject::f()" << std::endl;
}

void GravitySources::f()
{
    std::cout << "GravitySources::f() " << _label << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MovableObject mo;
    GravitySources gs[3] {1, 2, 3}; // 3 GravitySources
    mo.integrate(gs, 3); // process them
}
```

Comment: I have and idean to create StaticGravitySource and use it in MovableObject and then make multiply inheritance:
GravitySource: public StaticGravitySource, MovableObject
What can you say about it?

Comment: @Robotex I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve using multiple inheritance. Why not using just simple inheritance and control via a pointer?

Comment: I did as you said. Thank you